# Unable to import djstripe.models to views.py

Tags: django, stripe-payments

All the migrations have been successful and all the models and tables have been imported successfully by running below command:

```sh
python3 manage.py djstripe_sync_plans_from_stripe
```

[image]

but I can't import djstripe.models in my ***views.py*** module, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using dj-strip 2.4 or later `djstripe_sync_plans_from_stripe` command base on [dj-strip 2.4 release note](https://dj-stripe.dev/dj-stripe/2.6/history/2_4_0/#creating-plans-from-the-django-admin-is-no-longer-supported) is a deprecated command and for migrate tables that's enough to run below commands:

```sh
$ python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py djstripe_sync_models
```